# Cannot detect individual UPPER or lower case using search

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following Code

```js
var theValue = 'Monkey123' //UPPER CASE Missed
//var theValue = 'abcABC123!'  //lower case Missed
currentComplexityCount = 0;

if (theValue.search(/[a-z]/g)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('lower case hit');
}
if (theValue.search(/[A-Z]/g)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('UPPER case hit');
}
if (theValue.search(/[0-9]/g)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('Number hit');
}
console.log('Your complexity Count: ' + currentComplexityCount);
```

Essentially I need to recognize **separately** if a lower case and UPPER case character exists.  Notice each sample string will trigger either the UPPER or lower case condition, but both should trigger both.

The complexity count for both examples should be 3.  What am I doing wrong with my regex?

(*no jQuery please*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.search()` returns the first index of the found item, which in the case of you Upper Case search is 0, which evaluates to false.

Try using [`regex.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead:

```js
var theValue = 'Monkey123'     //UPPER CASE Missed
currentComplexityCount = 0;

if (/[a-z]/.test(theValue)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('lower case hit');
}
if (/[A-Z]/.test(theValue)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('UPPER case hit');
}
if (/[0-9]/.test(theValue)){
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('Number hit');
}
console.log('Your complexity Count: ' + currentComplexityCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use test instead.  Your question looked like you wanted to combine the upper and lower test.  I did this in the below.

```
var theValue = 'Monkey123' //UPPER CASE Missed
//var theValue = 'abcABC123!'  //lower case Missed
currentComplexityCount = 0;

if (/[a-z]/g.test(theValue)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('lower case hit');
}

if (/[A-Z]/g.test(theValue)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('upper case hit');
}
if (/[0-9]/g.test(theValue)) {
  currentComplexityCount++;
  console.log('Number hit');
}
console.log('Your complexity Count: ' + currentComplexityCount);
```

Comment: I wanted to detect them *individually*, upper and lower case.

Comment: @MisterPositive I updated it to ask individually.  You should use test instead of search or match because you are really looking for a boolean value of yes it meets the criteria or no it doesn't.

Comment: Yep, test seems the way to go here thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

So a easy way to achieve what you want is this but I didnt use search

```
    function hasLowerCase(str) {
            if(str.toUpperCase() != str) {
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: How does this code detect lower and upper case letters separately?